# The Qt Quick Application doesn't build a .apk file

Tags: android, qt, qt-quick

Using a `Qt Quick Application` (project name: *SimpleUI*), I ran [this example](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch01/index.html#digesting-an-user-interface) using the Desktop kit correctly.

Then went for testing the app using both Android for *armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.0 for Android armv7)* and *Android for x86 (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.0 for Android x86)* kits in both *Debug* and *Release* modes. I don't have an Android device and used emulators for both non-Desktop kits, although they didn't show the output of the app!

Now my folder looks [like this](https://s1.postimg.org/9hs8gpthb/Capture.png), and I searched the `.apk` file to test it somewhere else and searched the folders by `*.apk` keyword but I [couldn't find](https://s1.postimg.org/qpql2b8e7/Capture.png) such a file!

I searched the web and was asked about my **API** levels. My **SDK** looks like below:

[image]

I don't use `Ant` but `Gradle` instead of that.

Using the *SimpleUI* project I went through its path and found details for both architectures.
Here is for [the Arm](https://s2.postimg.org/ksgogdnbt/image.png) and this one for [the x86](https://s1.postimg.org/pe87hmiv3/image.png).

What is the problem please?

Qt Creator IDE ver: 4.3.0
Qt ver: 5.9

Comment: I've had issues the last time I tried using the newest version of the android sdk and ndk. I ended up using ndk 10e and sdk api level 18. I recall problems with gradle as well. It says that and has been depricated and gradle is forced from 25 otnward. I'd suggest dialing back on the versions, google tends to break a lot of stuff that Qt relies on in newer versions, and it takes a looooot of time for Qt to catch up on those changes.

Comment: @dtech: My *ndk* is *android-ndk-r10e*. Do you think if I install stuff for *API* lower level, say, 18, and create an ADV by that, the issue will be solved? And If so, won't it be using 22 or 23?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I know that the latest android stuff didn't work for me, while the stuff I listed does.

Comment: Gradle actually works for me with my current toolchain, but I am not really keen on touching the rest out of fear something might get broken :) There were times I did struggle quite a lot before getting Qt for android to build successfully and consistently.

Comment: Me too, so far. I even sometimes think that whether is Qt a correct choice for creating Android apps? What was your choice? Do you use Qt for creating Android apps?

Comment: I [updated the SDK](https://s2.postimg.org/nv6az0eu1/image.png) and created an [Arm](https://s2.postimg.org/u2sfyysft/image.png) *AVD* and ran the app and waited until the end. It says, at the end: *FAILURE: Build failed with an exception*. [This screen](https://s2.postimg.org/a1om32dbt/image.png) and [this one](https://s2.postimg.org/dqy1q0g6x/image.png) are the full message.

Comment: Don't you have an android device? The AVD is garbage, I repeat, **GARBAGE**. I've gotten it to work in the past, but it was so brutally slow, and had to kill it from the task manager after every use, now I only build and then manually deploy the APK on devices for testing, I don't even use creator's own deployment, because I've had my fair share of issues with that as well.

Comment: And I also repeat, it's garbage. I don't have an Android device. This is my purpose too, but the building process won't get succeeded. My approach is using the AVDs to create the *.apk* file and send it to friends to test it on their Android devices for real. I think the Qt Creator IDE and ADVs' simplest task is to create the *.apk* file but I don't know why they fail! :(

Comment: You don't need an AVD to create an apk. You simply need to press the build button (build without run that is). It is not a good idea to not have any android device when you develop android apps. At the very least a cheap phone and/or tablet.

Comment: It solved my issue. :-) Thanks. By using AVDs I just wanted to have the APK files and I din't know using this simple way the IDE creates them. I've installed a *Remix OS Player* on my Windows machine and by an app I transfer the APK files into it, and by that OS, I test them. It worked now. Thanks again.